# how to remove options on button click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me
how to remove options on button click in jquery ?
I want to remove all options of 2,3 dropdown expect first option .

can we pass any condition in `eq` in which i pass index it remove all options of all dropsdown 
(greater than index)

https://jsbin.com/raleqolere/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
  $('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(){
    var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
    //remove all options expect first greater the 1 position  
    $('.dropdowns_js').eq(1).remove();
  })
})
```

in other words I want to remove all options expect first of  data-key="district" , data-key="branch"

Comment: `$('#select option').not(':first').remove()`

Comment: it remove options from all select or dropdown

Comment: I need only for 2,3 .can we pass condition in `eq`

Comment: `#select` was just an example. You need to amend it to your needs.

Comment: can we use `eq`

Comment: You could, but you'd need to select each option manually which is a little pointless, and too robust if the number of `option` elements changes at any point in future. Excluding the `:first`, as in my first comment, makes far more sense

Comment: so you want to remove second and third one right

Comment: yes ..I need to do that

Comment: @user5711656 Hope you need this https://jsbin.com/necujazaku/edit?html,js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to remove all option rather than first options in each select-box

Do like below:-

```
$(function(){
  $('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(){
    var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
    //which have  key`state` append options
    $('.dropdowns_js').append(option)
  });
  $('.ifsc_clearbankbtn').click(function(){    
    $('.dropdowns_js').each(function(){      
      $(this).find("option:gt(1)").remove();
    });
  })
})
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(){
    var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
    //which have  key`state` append options
    $('.dropdowns_js').append(option)
  });
  $('.ifsc_clearbankbtn').click(function(){    
    $('.dropdowns_js').each(function(){      
      $(this).find("option:gt(1)").remove();
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div data-dropdown="ifsc_dropdowns">
<div class="ifsc_details">
<form>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="bank">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Bank</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="state">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select State</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="district">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select District</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js" data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="branch">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Branch</option>
        </select>
    </span>

    <button type="button"  data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" class="ifsc_getbankbtn">Get IFSC code</button>
    <button type="button"  data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" class="ifsc_clearbankbtn">Remove IFSC code</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(){
    var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
    //which have  key`state` append options
    $('.dropdowns_js').append(option)
  });
  $('.ifsc_clearbankbtn').click(function(){    
    var index = 1;  // set index value as per you requirement.  
    $('.dropdowns_js').each(function(a,b){ 
       if(a > index)
       {        
         var defaultOption=b.options[0];
         $(this).html('');
         $(this).html(defaultOption);
       }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div data-dropdown="ifsc_dropdowns">
<div class="ifsc_details">
<form>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="bank">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Bank</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="state">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select State</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="district">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select District</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select class="dropdowns_js" data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="branch">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Branch</option>
        </select>
    </span>

    <button type="button"  data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" class="ifsc_getbankbtn">Get IFSC code</button>
    <button type="button"  data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" class="ifsc_clearbankbtn">Remove IFSC code</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set index=1 then it will remove options from last 2 drop-down (District & Branch)